# Segmentation fault in c++ program using vector

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I received a segfault when running my code. The code contains a for loop and segmentation fault doesn't appear when I run the program for smaller iterations. It appears when I run the code for the larger loop.
I used a debugger to check where doe the problem occurs:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004062d0 in std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::push_back (
    this=0x64dc08, __x=@0x7fffffffd180: 32)
    at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:915
915     if (this->_M_impl._M_finish != this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage)
```

What does it mean? Does anyone know? The code error is related to this part of the code:

```
  int box_new = getBoxID(x[i],y[i],R0,nbox);
            if(bx[i] != box_new)
                {
                vector<int>::iterator position = std::find(box_particles[bx[i]].begin(), box_particles[bx[i]].end(), i);
                if (position != box_particles[bx[i]].end()) // .end() means the element was not found
                    box_particles[bx[i]].erase(position);
                bx[i] = box_new;
                box_particles[box_new].push_back(i);
                }
```

Comment: *The code contains a for loop* We badly want to see the loop.

Comment: Posting your code might be helpful. But it looks like you are trying to access past the size of your vector.

Comment: I con not recognize which part of the code is it. How can I find the line of the fault? @kjpus

Comment: I have added the related part of the code @GauravSehgal

Comment: Divide and conquer. Remove everything from the program that is not required to trigger the bug. Basically, make a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Because value of `box_new` is out of bound, that is, it may be larger than or equals to the size of `box_particles` or less than 0. Then corruption occur and 
segfault.

Please make sure `box_new` is in the range`[0, box_particles.size())`. Note that this range may change at each iteration.

Comment: there are more things in the code, but I have ignored them

Comment: The error occurs when some time passes, not in the first calculations of the loop

Comment: Do you know the reason resuting in the problem?

Comment: You mean you have written your previous answer in other words?